# How to check if given enum is string based or numeric in Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

I have two enums which are defined like this:

```
enum Ed {
  up,
  down,
  left,
  right,
}

//or 

enum Es {
  A = "a",
  B = "b",
  C = "c",
}
```

So  I need a function `isStringEnum` which for `isStringEnum(Ed)` or `isStringEnum(Ed.up)` will return false. For `isStringEnum(Es)` or `isStringEnum(Es.A)` will return true.

Thanks

Comment: enums can have numeric and string members simultaneously. What should the function return for this case?

Comment: Let's assume these are either strictly numeric or strictly string based enums.

Comment: You could just check whether all the property values are `string`s or not like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3XKbW).  Does that meet your needs?  (Note that a numeric enum will have *some* `string` property values, since they include reverse mappings).  If so I could write up an answer; if not, please show the use case where it fails.  (You will need to mention me via @jcalz if you want me to be alerted, btw)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
function isStringEnum(e: object){
  return Object.entries(e).every(e => typeof e[1] === "string")
}

console.log(isStringEnum(Ed)) // false
console.log(isStringEnum(Es)) // true
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwdgrgtgBAogExgb2DGEAOAaNMED2A7mLugDYgBmALmTAE4CWA5gBZ3AC%20wwA9HwIMYvcNHgBnFHgCCMALwwARAEMl9AEILlAI3V4AwtqUBjfT2BUIYEzSYEwMJhIDKNZmBZxIUABQgALhgCHQArEFsASlR0BhAaCAZHAHkwiJoAOnB3JhAJf0isgDcQBgBPfwUAPhgaMswQAioYEABtAEYAXQV5RSUJHM8lSO5eEwcJAkoM8gIWX2c3Dy8fX0RIkfGwSenZ%20cXBleg1iQ2gA)

Comment: This works, but involves iteraing through all values of the enum. Is it possible to get the answer in `O[1]`?

Comment: @husayt - You could just check the first element.

Comment: @TobiasS. No you can't.  The first element will almost certainly be a reverse mapping if it's a numeric enum.  [Try yourself and see](https://tsplay.dev/wXjgom).

Comment: @husayt I don't see any part of the question where you care about the time complexity (especially since unless you have enums with millions of entries I can't imagine how such things would even be a concern for you).  If you care about that you should put it in the question explicitly.

Comment: I guess checking the last element could work then.

Comment: I'd really want to understand *why* we are limiting ourselves to checking one small piece of an object if we're trying to accurately classify it, before hoping that we could rely on property ordering.  (Not to mention that determining the last element would probably involve iterating properties to begin with... `Object.entries()` produces an array eagerly.  A `for...in` loop could exit early but you're hitting the first elements first.)